# Amazon EC2 instances w/ IP/Domain

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have 2 micro instances on my EC2 account. I've been using putty with the public dns address to gain ssh access to the servers. How can I make it so they both have a dedicated IP address and then add a domain name from another source such as host gator or godaddy?

If I would turn on/off the instances, the dedicated IP would stay put right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add Elastic IP address to your instances.
and yes, if you turn off the instance, the IP will be lost, but you can Re-Attach it to server, after it is brought online instantly.

Comment: Thanks for the responce Frank. I'm on the AWS EC2 web console now and I'm making a new elastic ip, is this the dedicated IP? Can I make one for each instance?

Comment: I've got an ip attached to an instance. Just to clarify, if I turn off the instance the elastic IP will change?

Comment: yes, this is the Dedicated IP address. and Yes, you can create new IP and attach it to every instance  you have.

Answer (score 1):

> If I would turn on/off the instances, the dedicated IP would stay put
>   right?

Yes, an elastic IP would stay put while you turn off and on the instances. If you don't associate your elastic IP with an instance, you'll be charged at $0.01 per hour, though.

If your host doesn't allow creating an "A" record in the DNS zone file, you might want to use a free DNS service such as zoneedit.com to achieve the same result. GoDaddy does allow creating an 'A' record. Not sure about hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate and associate an elastic IP address with each of your instances.  When allocated, they're yours until you release them.  You can associate them with any running instance.  When the instance stops, the ip address will be disassociated from the instance but still allocated to you.  When you restart the instance, you'll need to re-associate the ip address.

You can then create a DNS A record using godaddy etc. for the ip address.